# Undefined method 'build' in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting a "NoMethodError in ProjectsController#create" with the following code:

```
def create
  @project = current_user.project.build(params[:project])
  if @project.save
    flash[:success] = "Project created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

I have tried using `@project = current_user.project.create(params[:project])` as well, but I get the same error, albeit for `.create`.

My Project model looks like this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title,
                  :sub_title,
                  :desc,
                  :category

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 35 }
  validates :category, presence: true

  belongs_to  :user
  ...
end
```

and my User model looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name,
                  :surname,
                  :email,
                  :email_confirmation,
                  :password,
                  :password_confirmation

  has_secure_password

  has_one :project
  ...
end
```

From what I can tell, this should create a new Project with an association to the `user.id` and `project.user_id`.  Any ideas why I get the error instead of successful creation?

Comment: Does it say undefined method build for User:Class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `has_one` associations you want:

```
@project = current_user.build_project(params[:project])
```

The same pattern is used for create:

```
@project = current_user.create_project(params[:project])
```

If you look at the [has_one documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one) they list the methods that get created when you declare the association.

Comment: That worked, thanks!  Can you explain the difference for us learning Rails?  I got my information from [link]railstutorial.org, and it didn't offer any explanation as to why...

Comment: I think the main reason is that for `has_one` you are dealing straight with an `ActiveRecord` object vs with `has_many` you are dealing with a collection of `ActiveRecord` objects. That extra structure containing those `ActiveRecord` objects has methods added onto it, but they can't do that very well with a singular `ActiveRecord` object that results from a `has_one` (Especially if it doesn't exist yet!). It is highly confusing, though, and it catches a lot of people!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I wish that more of StackOverflows' answers explained the reasons behind the answers more, instead of just giving and answer.